# How to GROUP BY the result/return value of LEFT JOIN in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

i have 3 tables that i want to join.

entries table

```
| entry_id | entry_title                |
|----------|----------------------------|
| 1        | Hello World!               |
| 2        | Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet |
| 3        | Foo Title Foo Title        |
```

comment table

```
| comment_id | comment_content       | comment_entry_id |
|------------|-----------------------|------------------|
| 1          | lorem ipsum is great! | 1                |
| 2          | foo is great!         | 1                |
| 3          | Hello World!          | 2                |
| 4          | Hello Word!           | 3                |
```

threaded_comment table

```
| threaded_comment_id | threaded_comment_content | threaded_comment_comment_id |
|---------------------|--------------------------|-----------------------------|
| 1                   | i agree foo!             | 2                           |
| 2                   | Yes Foo!                 | 2                           |
| 3                   | Lorem Ipsum is great!    | 1                           |
| 4                   | Ah yes, Hello World!     | 4                           |
```

Here's some information about it:

1. `comment_entry_id` column is a *non-identifying foreign key* for `comment` table to `entries` table
2. `threaded_comment_comment_id` column is a *non-identifying foreign key* for `threaded_comment` table to `comment` table

I wanted to have the total comments and threaded comments in every entries,
so i did this:

```sql
SELECT entries.entry_title AS entry_title,
       COUNT(comment.comment_id) AS total_of_comments,
       COUNT(threaded_comment.threaded_comment_id) AS total_of_threaded_comments,
       COUNT(comment.comment_id) + COUNT(threaded_comment.threaded_comment_id) AS total_of_comments_and_threaded_comments
FROM entries
  LEFT JOIN comment
  ON entries.entry_id = comment.comment_entry_id
  LEFT JOIN threaded_comment
  ON threaded_comment.threaded_comment_comment_id = comment.comment_id
GROUP BY entries.entry_id
```

and this is what i got

```
| entry_title                | total_of_comments | total_of_threaded_comments | total_of_comments_and_threaded_comments |
|----------------------------|-------------------|----------------------------|-----------------------------------------|
| Hello World                | 2                 | 1                          | 3                                       |
| Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet | 2                 | 2                          | 4                                       |
| Foo Title Foo Title        | 1                 | 0                          | 1                                       |
```

As you can see, in the "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet" row i got 2 `total_of_comments` while i only got 1 comment with 2 threaded comments in it.
I know that happened because i didn't `GROUP BY` the `comment.comment_id` so it will repeat the same `comment.comment_id` when there's more than 1 threaded comment in it.

so my question is, how can i use multiple `GROUP BY` statement while i already have 1 `GROUP BY` statement in query? OR can i use `GROUP BY` statement inside `LEFT JOIN` query?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you need in simple `COUNT(DISTINCT column)`? This will collapse a lot of the same column values to `1`.

Comment: I agree with @Akina, I cant understand exactly what you want but pretty sure `count distinct` is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments suggest, you could apply `COUNT DISTINCT` on the comment_id column only.

```
SELECT entries.entry_title,
       COUNT(DISTINCT comment.comment_id) AS total_of_comments,
       COUNT(threaded_comment.threaded_comment_id) AS total_of_threaded_comments,
       COUNT(DISTINCT comment.comment_id) + COUNT(threaded_comment.threaded_comment_id) AS total_of_comments_and_threaded_comments
FROM entries
  LEFT JOIN comment
  ON entries.entry_id = comment.comment_entry_id
  LEFT JOIN threaded_comment
  ON threaded_comment.threaded_comment_comment_id = comment.comment_id
GROUP BY entries.entry_title
```

The other route that you could follow, it would be to count the threaded comments in a subquery.

```
SELECT entries.entry_title, 
  COUNT(comment.comment_id) AS total_of_comments, 
  CASE WHEN SUM(B.total_1) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE SUM(B.total_1) END AS total_of_threaded_comments 
FROM comment
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT threaded_comment_comment_id, COUNT(threaded_comment_id) AS total_1
             FROM threaded_comment 
             GROUP BY threaded_comment_comment_id)B
  ON B.threaded_comment_comment_id = comment.comment_id
  LEFT JOIN entries
  ON entries.entry_id = comment.comment_entry_id
GROUP BY entries.entry_title
```

Find an indicative [answer](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=371b7e771b1af34048506da9a3013168).